# How to make .m of a dicom image analysis application platfom independent

Tags: java, matlab, dicom

I am having .m file which is an application of dicom image analysis. I want to run .m file under the java platform (Or any other option to make my application platform independent) so that I can run it on any system which may not be having matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options to deploy code, one is the Matlab builder JA which generates jar files from your M code.
To use the jar files, the Matlab compiler runtime (MCR)  has to be installed on the target system. It is available for download for free.